# MySQL different versions other results

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

hey, i have 2 version of mysql on windows 5.1.39-community and on linux 5.1.39-log
i execute a query:

```
SELECT `o`.`idOffer`, 

       `o`.`offer_date`, 
       `p`.`factory`, 
       `c`.`short` AS `company`, 
       `s`.`name` AS `subcategory`, 
       `ct`.`name` AS `category`,
       count( (select count(1) from product where idProduct=idOffer group by idOffer) ) as b
 FROM `Offer` AS `o` 
 LEFT JOIN `Product` AS `p` ON o.idOffer = p.idOffer 
 LEFT JOIN `company` AS `c` ON o.company = c.id 
 LEFT JOIN `Subcategory` AS `s` ON s.idSubcategory = o.idSubcategory 
 LEFT JOIN `Category` AS `ct` ON ct.idCategory = s.idCategory 
 WHERE (o.idOffer = p.idOffer) GROUP BY `o`.`idOffer`
```

on windows it works as it suppose, but on linux it says:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

is it any way to get it worked on linux without any mysql updates/downgrades ?

Comment: Isn't the `group by idOffer` clause in the subquery superfluous because of `where idProduct=idOffer` anyway? Just try it without the group by in the subquery.

Comment: It works, thanks, wouldnt think about this.
Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your SQL "as b" columnResult is based specifically on a SQL, and the WHERE clause of the of the idOffer already qualifies and SHOULD be the same, I would remove the group by of this columnar element.  I can only assume there might be some white-space data or other that is falsely getting included and "ID1" is different than "ID1 " is getting falsely interpretted.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this has anything to do with it, but Linux MySQL tables are case sensitive while Windows tables are not (because of the filesystem, I suspect), anyway, you have `Product` and `product` and that will cause some problems.

Don't know if it really is the cause of the problem in your question, but it is a wall you may end up flying smack into and I thought it should be brought up.